# Azure SQL Database Copying in the Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azureportal

As the Azure Account owner, I have universal access, and can make copies of my databases in the Portal.

However, my team members, who are members of Active Directory groups cannot.  because their Target Server list is empty.

I have granted the AD groups access (via the Access Control menu option) to both our database severs (and the owning resource group).  So they are able to access the database server, but still they are unable to see it in their list of Target Servers when they try to make a copy.

Does anyone know what permissions are required to populate the Target Server list when copying databases?

Thanks,

Max.

Comment: what's the access role did you grant to the Active Directory group members?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please reference this document [Copy database within Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy?tabs=azure-powershell):

**When you copy a database to a different SQL Database server, the security principal on the new server becomes the database owner on the new database.** If you use contained database users for data access, ensure that both the primary and secondary databases always have the same user credentials, so that after the copy is complete you can immediately access it with the same credentials.

If you want to see target SQL Server, the AD group members also should have the permission to access other resources in  your subscriptions.

Make sure they are in the same subscription or add the role(I tried `reader`, `owner` and `contributor` and works well) to the member from Subscription IAM,:
[image]

Hope this help.